# If we can see the light reflected off objects, why can't we "see" light?

Tags: visible-light, photons, reflection, scattering

It's said that light is invisible because photons don't strike each other, then why we do see the reflected light from other objects?

Answer (score 2):

when photons strike material objects, they are not bouncing off other photons- they are bouncing off clouds of electrons. Depending on how those electrons are being shared by adjacent atoms, the incident photons can either be reflected off or absorbed.

Answer (score 1):

Photons are not the only things in the universe. In fact, normal matter consisting of half-integer spin fermions do interact with light and can change their paths and reflect, absorb or emit them. Try reading Richard Feynman's quantum electrodynamics lectures. They are a good introduction to quantum electrodynamics and give you an accurate representation about our current best understanding of this light-matter interaction.